# Unable to run C program in visual studio code on mac

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, executable

I am unable to run my c program in visual studio code! I compiles correctly since the executable is in the same directory as the main.c file I am trying to run. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and my tasks.json that did not generate automatically but I had to manually add it via cmd + shift + p and search for tasks

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "gcc build active file",
        "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "/usr/bin"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

It is the same output from building the program with gcc and clang

```
> Executing task: /usr/bin/gcc -g '/Users/usrname/Documents/C Programming/main.c' -o '/Users/usrname/Documents/C Programming/main' <


Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I have installed xcode, both the IDE and the other thingy people recommend installing from terminal "xcode --install" or something like that. I can compile code easily in CLion and from terminal as well as run it, so compiling is obviously not an issue.

The output is blank.

Again this is on mac Mojave latest version running latest version of visual studio code. And yes I have installed the c/c++ extension from the addons page inside the app.

Comment: In the terminal tab, choose the `cppdbg` terminal instead of `task`, and you will see the output.

Comment: There is no "cppdbg" in the terminal tab...

Comment: It should look like this. https://pasteboard.co/ICpjKfF.png

Comment: @KagurazakaKotori I do not have that, I only have "Task - gcc build active file"

Comment: I have the same issue, did you figure it out?